# Limitar quantidade de arquivos no DropZone.js

Tags: dropzonejs

Pessoal tou usando o plugin Dropzone.js para enviar imagens e estou precisando limitar a quantidade de imagens que eu envio nele. Por exemplo quero limitar a 5 arquivos no total. Ai ele so poderá enviar para o servidor e exibir os 5 arquivos. Como eu faço isto nele?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<form class="dropzone" id="meuDropZone"></form>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
Dropzone.options.meuDropZone = {
  accept: function(file, done) {
    console.log("uploaded");
    done();
  },
  init: function() {
    this.on("addedfile", function() {
      if (this.files[5]!=null){
        this.removeFile(this.files[5]);
        alert("Limite de 5 arquivos excedido!");
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: assim como eu expliquei acima para o João Manolo este codigo que você postou so limita a quantidade de arquivos que você pode escolher de uma unica vez. Tente ai enviando um arquivo por vez e vera que você conseguira enviar mais de 5 arquivos. Obrigado

Comment: @JoaoNivaldo, atualizei o código, veja se funciona por favor.

Comment: funcionou em partes. Quando eu estou com 5 arquivos exibidos e clico em outro ele da a mensagem de limite mas apaga quinto arquivo que ja estava enviado e substitui pelo 6 arquivo.

Comment: Tente agora Joao!

Comment: amigo para dar certinho foi so trocar o files[4] por files[5] e tudo certo. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Opa, essa era minha dúvida, se o evento era chamado DEPOIS de o arquivo ser adicionado! Show.

Answer (score 2):

Basta adicionar `maxFiles:`, lembrando que o correto é você também validar do lado do servidor quantos aquivos que estão subindo.

```
   $("div#myDropZone").dropzone({
        url: "ACTION/SERVIDOR",
        autoProcessQueue: true,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        parallelUploads: 1,
        maxFilesize: 5,
        <!--Adicione o Maximo de arquivos-->
        maxFiles: 8,
        acceptedFiles: "image/jpeg"

    });
```

Comment: Então @João Manolo esta propriedade ela limita apenas quantos arquivos você pode escolher por vez na multi-seleção. Eu preciso por exemplo eu ja cliquei em 3 arquivos e ele mostrou as minuatura destes 3 arquivos ai se eu tentar enviar mais 4 ele tem que dar a mensagem que o limite é 5. Espero ter conseguido me explicar.

Comment: Então @JoaoNivaldo, eu entendi. A configuração que consta na documentação oficial que controla o limite de arquivos é `maxFiles:` caso extrapole o limite informado o evento `maxfilesexceeded` é chamado. Tente adicionar `parallelUploads: 1`, pois ele fara o upload assincrono apenas um arquivo por vez.